# "cannot receive new filesystem stream: invalid backup stream" error when unpacking flash archive on solaris 10

Tags: solaris-10, automated-install, provisioning, operating-system

I've searched around but i'm having no luck with some peculiar behavior with a flash archive.

I'm using HP Server Automation 9.14 to deploy the OS.

I'm creating a Solaris 10 flash archive to create a snapshot default build in our environment.

I create the flash archive with

```
# flar create -c -S -n g8-solaris10-u10  g8-solaris10-u10.flar
```

It seems to create the file without any problems (exit status 0).

When deploying to a new system (same hardware), it extracts to a point and then bails.

The last error in the log I can see is
    Extracted 2047.00 MB ( 82% of 2488.98 MB archive)

```
ERROR: Could not read file (172.27.118.100:/media/opsware/sunos/flar/g8-solaris10-u10.flar
ERROR: Errors occurred during the extraction of flash archive. The file /tmp/flash_errors contains the list of errors encountered

ERROR: Could not extract Flash archive
ERROR: Flash installation failed
```

The error log contained the following message

```
cannot receive new filesystem stream: invalid backup stream
```

A previous version of this flash archive (1.8gb) worked ok, so I suspect size may be a factor.

The source system (the one the flash archive is an image of) is an HP BL460C GEN8
some more info below.

## OS version Info

```
# uname -a
SunOS testhostname 5.10 Generic_147441-01 i86pc i386 i86pc

# who -r
   .       run-level 3  Oct 15 08:15     3      0  S
```

## disks

```
# echo | format
Searching for disks...done


AVAILABLE DISK SELECTIONS:
       0. c0t0d0 <DEFAULT cyl 17841 alt 2 hd 255 sec 63>
          /pci@0,0/pci8086,3c06@2,2/pci103c,3355@0/sd@0,0
Specify disk (enter its number): Specify disk (enter its number):
```

## zpools

```
# zpool list
NAME    SIZE  ALLOC   FREE    CAP  HEALTH  ALTROOT
rpool   136G  24.6G   111G    18%  ONLINE  -
```

## Zones

```
# zoneadm list -cv
  ID NAME             STATUS     PATH                           BRAND    IP
  0 global           running    /                              native   shared
```

The file size of 2047 seems suspiciously close to 2048, which is concerning.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks